# Masked input vuejs without jQuery

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, maskedinput

Can anybody ask datepicker plugin, that can be available to input some date or choose a date from the calendar (without jQuery)? Entered value must be masked

Comment: All vue plugins are not masked when enter some value

Comment: Do you mean masked like [this](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/)?

Comment: Yea, like this, but there is no datepicker. I can use some plugin like a _vue-masked-input_, but I need _"datepicker + mask without jQuery"_

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#date-formatting) accepts a "format" argument, which is a mask. If the format doesn't work the way you need it to, you could probably write a [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) to add a mask to the `input` element.